# Java: Is it possible to close a package (restrict adding classes to it)

Tags: java, security, package

The title pretty much says all. 
If I provide a library and someone uses it he can write classes and add them to packages that are defined by my library. However this rises security issues as this would mean that he gets access to methods within the library that are defined without access modifier.

Is there a solution to forbid a user to add classes to an existing package?

Comment: I personally doubt someone would actually do it. it would take a lot more than just importing a .jar and using it.
but in the end, just like with decompiling: not distributing your jar is about the only 100% sure thing you can do.

Comment: @Stultuske Depends on the context. I would totally abuse a library.

Comment: I never said it wasn't possible, just that most users won't (feel the) need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (but). The `sealed` manifest attribute will seal a package, preventing classes from other sources from being included. [(technote)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Per-Entry_Attributes)

Though it kind of depends on the context. If the someone using it gets to play with the library jar file first, then it's game over.

If both the library and client code is loaded by the same class loader, then that is in generally problematic, although classes signed with different signatures cannot coexist within the same package. If different class loaders are used even with a parent-child relationship, then at runtime packages with the same name but loaded by different class loaders are different packages.

For Java PlugIn and Java WebStart, `Trusted-Library` manifest entry causes the jar to be slid into a parent class loader, protecting it from potentially untrusted application code.